# Pandas set_levels on MultiIndex: Level values must be unique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

Given a DataFrame `df`

```
                    Value
Category Pool Class      
A        1.0  1.0       1
              9.0       2
B        1.0  1.0       3
C        1.0  1.0       4
              5.0       5
```

I want to convert the levels `Pool` and `Class` to integers without `reset_index` (see below).

I tried using a combination of `get_level_values` and `set_levels` like so

```
for c in ['Pool', 'Class']:
    df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values(c).astype(int), level=c, inplace=True)
```

However, this raises

```
ValueError: Level values must be unique: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] on level 1
```

To understand what happens, I also tried using `verify_integrity=False`. Then

```
df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values('Class').astype(int),
                    level='Class', verify_integrity=False, inplace=True)
```

produces

```
                    Value
Category Pool Class      
A        1.0  1         1
              1         2
B        1.0  1         3
C        1.0  1         4
              9         5
```

whereas my goal is to obtain

```
                    Value
Category Pool Class      
A        1.0  1         1
              9         2
B        1.0  1         3
C        1.0  1         4
              5         5
```

How to achieve this properly? Is chaining of `get_level_values` and `set_levels` the correct way to do it? Why is `pandas` not able to properly set the level after having it transformed with `astype`?

I guess you could work with `reset_index` and `set_index` but what is the benefit then of having the methods `set_levels`?

```
d = {'Category': str, 'Pool': int, 'Class': int}
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
for k, v in d.items():
    df[k] = df[k].astype(v)

df.set_index(list(d.keys()), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access index levels directly via `pd.MultiIndex.levels` and feed to [`pd.MultiIndex.set_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[2].astype(int), level=2)

print(df)

                     Value
Category Pool Class       
A        1.0  1          1
              9          2
B        1.0  1          3
C        1.0  1          4
              5          5
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I refer to the levels by names? In fact, I have a `dict` of level names and types which I want to use for conversion. Also, what is the reason for the `ValueError` above?

Comment: `levels` is different to `get_level_values` and the former is what `set_levels` expects. `levels` gets the unique indices, `get_level_values` gets every index. They are fundamentally different, test it for yourself. That's also likely why you get `ValueError`.

Comment: @jpp Is there some sort of a `set_level_values` method that complements `get_level_values`?

Comment: @Eran, To my knowledge, this doesn't exist. I only see `set_levels`.

Answer (score 5):

The following function can be used as a complement to `get_level_values`:

```
def set_level_values(midx, level, values):
    full_levels = list(zip(*midx.values))
    names = midx.names
    if isinstance(level, str):
        if level not in names:
            raise ValueError(f'No level {level} in MultiIndex')
        level = names.index(level)
    if len(full_levels[level]) != len(values):
        raise ValueError('Values must be of the same size as original level')
    full_levels[level] = values
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(full_levels, names=names)
```

Using this function, the solution for the original question would be:

```
for c in ['Pool', 'Class']:
    df.index = set_level_values(df.index, level=c, values=df.index.get_level_values(c).astype(int))
```

Comment: Super useful for me!!! - One level 1 of multiindex, I had not been able to replace multiindex values with another set of values (simply switching one index value for another), but rather wanted to assign to a list (where the length of the list equals the total length of my multiindex. level 1). This function accomplished the mission.

Answer (score 0):

To get the integer position that corresponds to a level name stored in variable `k`, you can use:

```
df.index.names.index(k)
```

**So if, like OP, you have a `dict` of level names and types, simply do:**

```
levels = [df.index.levels[df.index.names.index(k)].astype(v)
          for k, v in d.items()]
df.index = df.index.set_levels(levels=levels, level=d.keys())
```

Or, the same thing in a method chain:

```
df.set_index(
    df.index.set_levels(
        [df.index.levels[df.index.names.index(k)].astype(v)
         for k, v in d.items()],
        level=d.keys())
)...
```

---

Setup for OP's `DataFrame` and `dict`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    range(1, 6),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [
            ('A', 1., 1.),
            ('A', 1., 9.),
            ('B', 1., 1.),
            ('C', 1., 1.),
            ('C', 1., 5.)
        ],
        names=['Category', 'Pool', 'Class']
    ),
    columns=['Value']
)
d = {'Category': str, 'Pool': int, 'Class': int}
```

Comment: Note: The ```.keys()``` is not essential; simply ```level=d``` will be interpreted as just the keys anyway.